# How to create a bash function using if statement and variables

Tags: bash, zsh

By using `op bbc` I want to open bbc.com using my default browser and `op bbc safari` I want to open bbc.com using Safari. I created the following but it gives an error `op:1: = not found`. What am I doing wrong here?

I am using zsh on OSX.

```
function op() {
if [ "$2" == ""]
then
  open http://www."$1".com
else
  open -a "$2" http://www."$1".com
fi
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need spaces around `[` and `]`

```
if [ "$2" == "" ]
```

Also, for better portability, you should use `=` rather than `==`, and not use the `function` keyword when defining functions.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you recommend any books to learn for a beginner?

Comment: For even better compatibility, you might consider using `[ x"$2" = x"" ]`.  As with introductory texts, I found the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) to be most helpful.  It may appear a bit much information at first, but I learned to really appreciate it.